# Does publishing a paper on Qeios count as a prior publication from the viewpoint of a traditional peer reviewed journal?

Tags: publications

More specifically, for mathematics journals. Would a publication in [Qeios](https://www.qeios.com/) disqualify a paper from also being published in a traditional mathematics journal?

Comment: I don’t know the answer, but my personal experience with Qeios is that they occasionally randomly email me to look at some total crackpot junk, so I always assumed they were a promotion agency for bad papers.

Comment: The papers I saw there don’t get published in proper journals, but I can’t tell if that’s because of an official policy or something — they wouldn’t be able to pass peer review anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about the site you name, but math journals are quite understanding in general about prior publication of in-process papers. This is quite different from some other fields, though many others are coming around to the same policies. But, each journal will have its own policies on preprint publication.

Mathematicians are generally happy when they see results early on which, I'll guess, has led to this situation.

But as noted in the comments, publishing in junk journals or websites isn't a good sign about the quality of the paper. You still need to meet the standards of editors and reviewers. to be formally published.

And, if the consider themselves to be an "open access" journal, then it isn't the same as a preprint server, so many publishers, even in math, might decide it has been previously "published" not just something something something, that isn't quite publishing. Prior to arXiv the world was a bit clearer about what was publishing and what wasn't.

Comment: Well, not just "before arXiv", but, more precisely, "before there was an internet, and people could put documents on their .edu homepages"... :)

Answer (score 7):

It's unclear; some may consider it a journal, some may not. I suggest not to take the risk; it seems they offer no advantages over Arxiv.